# CUDA memory allocation performance

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm working with image filters on CUDA. Image processing is much faster than it is on CPU. But the problem is that the allocation of the image is really slow.

That is how I allocate memory and set the image.

```
hr = cudaMalloc(&m_device.originalImage,    size);                                                                          
hr = cudaMalloc(&m_device.modifiedImage,    size);                                                                          
hr = cudaMalloc(&m_device.tempImage,    size);                                                                  
hr = cudaMemset( m_device.modifiedImage, 0, size);                                                                          
hr = cudaMemcpy( m_device.originalImage, host.originalImage, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

And here is the result of executing the program.

```
C:\cpu_gpu_filters(GPU)\x64\Release>cpu_gpu_filters test-case.txt
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_1280x720.jpg
Init time: 519 ms
Time spent: 2.35542 ms
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_1366x768.jpg
Init time: 31 ms
Time spent: 2.68595 ms
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_1600x900.jpg
Init time: 44 ms
Time spent: 3.54835 ms
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_1920x1080.jpg
Init time: 61 ms
Time spent: 4.98131 ms
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_2560x1440.jpg
Init time: 107 ms
Time spent: 9.0727 ms
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_3840x2160.jpg
Init time: 355 ms
Time spent: 20.1453 ms
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_5120x2880.jpg
Init time: 449 ms
Time spent: 35.815 ms
C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test_set\cheshire_cat_7680x4320.jpg
Init time: 908 ms
Time spent: 75.4647 ms
```

**UPD** Code with time measuring:

```
start = high_resolution_clock::now();
Initialize();
stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
long long ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count();
long long us = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count();
cout << "Init time: " << ms << " ms" << endl;


start = high_resolution_clock::now();
GpuTimer gpuTimer;
gpuTimer.Start();
RunGaussianBlurKernel(
    m_device.modifiedImage,
    m_device.tempImage,
    m_device.originalImage, 
    m_device.filter,
    m_filter.width,
    m_host.originalImage.rows, 
    m_host.originalImage.cols
    );
gpuTimer.Stop();
```

The first image is the smallest, but initialization takes 519 ms. Maybe, it's because of the necessity to load the drivers or something. Then, when the size of the image increases, initialization time increases as well. Actually, this looks logical, but I'm still not sure that initialization process should be that slow. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where in your code are you measuring the start and end time?

Comment: @Makketronix, I'm pretty sure that the way I measure time is correct, but I updated the question. The question is whether it is normal that initialization takes so much time.

Comment: Hmm. Are you building in "Debug" or "Release"? I had performance issues before for "Debug" builds.

Comment: @Makketronix, I'm using "Release". The problem is that I'm not sure it should work faster, because 7680x4320 is a huge image. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I will add a possible answer. It won't fit under comments.

Comment: If you want an answer, you will need to provide an actual complete repro case. Random code snippets aren't helpful here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your unit code, you have a cudaMemset which execution time depends on size. There is also the cudaMemcpy, which execution time is approximately given by the mem copy size in bytes divided by the bandwidth of the PCI-Express. It is very likely that this part is responsible for the increase in init time. Running it through NSIGHT will provide you with more precise figures on execution time. However, without a MCVE, hard to answer for sure.

Comment: Well spotted. The initialisation time is scaling pretty much linearly with the image size because of the memset call.

Comment: I know that initialization time depends on the image size. I just did not expect that initialization could take that long.

Comment: @Max The init speed is only 100M/s if your pixel is char[3]. It's looks like H2D mem copy or disk loading rather than cudaMemset.

Comment: @Eric, just updated the answer commenting on the cudaMemcpy as well. Your point is very relevant though, I did not do the maths, but it is very likely that the file loading is part of the init phase.